# pass a selected list item to wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I let my user control know which item is selected in a list view control that's in a main window?

in the  image below, when I add items to the lower list view, I want to be able to select them and have the control that's on the right, updated with selected item's details
[image]

The main window is tied to a MainViewModel code. When I click the + button WO# items are added to the bottom list view. The list view is showing service items, whose properties are set with the right side window.

The right side is a custom control

```
    <TabItem Header="Service Items">
        <controls:ServiceItemsControl />
    </TabItem>
```

I created a ServiceItemsViewModel that works with the control and set the control's DataContext to it.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:PrettyLaborDuration x:Key="PrettyLaborDuration" />
    <vm:ServiceItemsViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FFFFFFFF" DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
```

Here's the ViewModel behind the control

[image]

In the MainViewModel this is what I use to access the selected item

```
private Service selectedServiceItem;
public Service SelectedServiceItem
{
    get { return selectedServiceItem; }
    set
    {
        //Labor.Time = (selectedServiceItem as Labor).Time;
        selectedServiceItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
    }
}
```

Labor derives from Service.

In the most basic terms, what I'm trying to do is set a variable within the control. Kind of like so:

```
<controls:ServiceItemsControl Labor="{Binding SelectedServiceItem}" />
```

So that Labor becomes what I'm working with in my ServiceItemsViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would do this by databinding the selected item on the control to a property on your model. You haven't really posted enough code for me to give you an exact example, but in the same manner that you bind values you can bind selectedValues allowing you to simply look at your model to see the selected value.

Comment: I added some more details. The very bottom is a summary of what I want to do in three short sentences.